# Format the content of a cell in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an ASP.NET `GridView` and some of the cells are clickable. I want to format the contents of these cells so that it's obvious they can be clicked on. If I do the following:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvResults.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || 
        row.RowType == DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow)
    {
        row.Cells[0].ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

The entire cell including the borders of the cell turn red. I just want the text in the cell to be red. How can I do this? My gridview autogenerates columns.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the `Related` links for a possable answer / solution

Comment: I've searched StackOverflow - don't see anything that answers my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinary ForeColor should affect text only.

In your case you can try something like

```
row.Cells[0].Text = "<span style='color:red'>" + row.Cells[0].Text + "</span>";
```

Another (and probably better) possibility is to do this via CSS. If it's a clickable link inside of table cell then following CSS should affect it

```
td > a {
   color: red;
}
```